# JQuery Accordion is shaky in SharePoint 2007

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a small prototype of a JQuery Accordion that I would like to use in SharePoint 2007. I can run it locally and it performs fine. When I put the code into a content editor web part in SharePoint 2007, the accordion works, but is shaky at the end of each animation. I read that it may have something to do with the doctype, but I have tried this and nothing has made the accordion perform smoothly in SharePoint. Any thoughts?

Link that I tried but did not work: http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2009/01/troubleshooting-jquery-accordion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem.

I used SharePoint Designer 2007 to create the accordion on a basic page - but within each 'tab' I put a Web Part Zone (WPZ) holding a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP). Each CEWP has various kinds of content. The reason for putting CEWPs within each tab is so the client can change the text/images themselves whenever they want.

However - the animation is craggy - and at the end of an expand or collapse action - the whole accordion sort of 'flashes' just before completion.

Using straightforward html versions of the accordion work fine.

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that there is a lot more code accompanying each CEWP - but I could be wrong.

Any insight by the experts would be appreciated.